# JQuery Data Tables server side processing with state saving

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery data tables with following initialization parameters

```
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"bStateSave": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
```

I get incorrect state of the pagination and information showed in the footer area, once I navigate to the end of the pagination and tried to fetch the same data again.

E.g.
Assume the default  number of records to be displayed is 10
(Bold text described bellow in the navigator is the enabled buttons)

- Step 01 - Fetching a set of data with 25 records
  *Showing 1 to 10 of 25 entries

  First | Previous | 1 | **2 | 3 | Next | Last***
- Step 02 - Navigating to the Last set of records
  *Showing 21 to 25 of 25 entries

  **First | Previous | 1 | 2 |** 3 | Next | Last*
- Step 03 - Navigating to data fetching page back
- Step 04 - Fetching the same old set of data with 25 records
  *Showing 21 to 30 of 25 entries

  **First | Previous | 1 | 2 |** 3 | Next | Last*
  **(PROBLEM !!!)**

Please note that this functionality works fine when the server side processing is not there

Comment: follow this tutorial http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-state-save-client-server-side/